# processDebugResources FAILED. No resource found that the fiven name 'dialogCornerRadius'

Tags: android, react-native

I don't understand why appear this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSl23.png) now. Yesterday and many days ago it worked well. This error had never appeared. I've not change settings.

I've tested before app vesrions and appears the same error. It had the same settings.

Why this error happens? Someone has some idea?

app/build.gradle

```
  android {
      compileSdkVersion 27
      buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.reactnavigationdrawer"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 26
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          ndk {
              abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
          }
      }
      signingConfigs {
         release {
             storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
             storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
             keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
             keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
         }
     }
      splits {
          abi {
              reset()
              enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
              universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
              include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
          }
      }
      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
              signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          }
      }
      // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
      applicationVariants.all { variant ->
          variant.outputs.each { output ->
              // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
              // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
              def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
              def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
              if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                  output.versionCodeOverride =
                          versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
              }
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
      compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')) {
       exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
      }
      compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
      compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.0")
      compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0')
      compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0')
      compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.0.1'
      compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.0.1'
      compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
      compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
      compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
      compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
      compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0') {
          force = true;
      }
  }
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+' // <- USE 2.2.+ version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {url"https://maven.google.com"}
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was appcompat version.

I had to change:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
```

to

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
```